# How to apply different equations to elements in a list based on if statements in Mathematica

Tags: if-statement, wolfram-mathematica, nested-lists, data-manipulation

I have a number of lists with each element representing a company.

For example:

```
b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} 
c = {3, 4, 6, 8, 9}
```

means Company 1 has b=1, c=3 and Company 2 has b=2, c=4 etc

I am trying to code a series of conditional statements without using loops.

For example, if Company 'x' has z > 0, then I want it to update a,d,g in one way, and if z < 0 i want it to update a,d,g in another way.

I tried using the If command but it doesn't seem to work for lists with multiple elements.

```
If [z > 0,
 a = b + c;
 d = e - f;
 g = h - i - j;
 ,
 a = n - o;
 d = p - q;
 g = w + y]
```

I have experimented with the MapThread command but can only seem to get it to work for one line of code. 
E.g. for a:

```
a = MapThread[If[#1 > 0, #2 + #3 , #4 - #5] &, {z, b, c, n, o}]
```

but this becomes cumbersome if i have to write this for each separate line.

Is there a simple way to implement this without using loops?

Comment: need a more complete example of input and expected output, and better asked on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few examples.

```
a = d = g = ConstantArray[Null, 5];
b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
c = {3, 4, 6, 8, 9};
e = {8, 4, 0, 4, 4};
f = {4, 9, 6, 5, 4};
h = {5, 8, 8, 7, 1};
i = {3, 3, 4, 4, 5};
j = {2, 6, 3, 4, 1};
n = {7, 3, 1, 8, 8};
o = {7, 8, 8, 4, 3};
p = {8, 3, 8, 9, 4};
q = {6, 5, 1, 6, 2};
w = {9, 5, 7, 7, 4};
y = {6, 5, 8, 9, 2};
z = {6, 2, 1, 3, 0};

Array[
  If[z[[#]] > 0,
    a[[#]] = b[[#]] + c[[#]];
    d[[#]] = e[[#]] - f[[#]];
    g[[#]] = h[[#]] - i[[#]] - j[[#]];
    ,
    a[[#]] = n[[#]] - o[[#]];
    d[[#]] = p[[#]] - q[[#]];
    g[[#]] = w[[#]] + y[[#]]] &, Length[z]];

{a, d, g}
```

> {{4, 6, 9, 12, 5}, {4, -5, -6, -1, 2}, {0, -1, 1, -1, 6}}

Using `MapThread` with local function names for clarity.

```
{a, d, g} = Transpose@MapThread[Function[
     {b, c, e, f, h, i, j, n, o, p, q, w, y, z},
     If[z > 0, {b + c, e - f, h - i - j}, {n - o, p - q, w + y}]],
    {b, c, e, f, h, i, j, n, o, p, q, w, y, z}]
```

> {{4, 6, 9, 12, 5}, {4, -5, -6, -1, 2}, {0, -1, 1, -1, 6}}

Using `ReplaceAll` with names localised by [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html).

```
{a, d, g} = Transpose[
  Transpose@{b, c, e, f, h, i, j, n, o, p, q, w, y, z} /.
   {b_, c_, e_, f_, h_, i_, j_, n_, o_, p_, q_, w_, y_, z_} :>
    If[z > 0, {b + c, e - f, h - i - j}, {n - o, p - q, w + y}]]
```

> {{4, 6, 9, 12, 5}, {4, -5, -6, -1, 2}, {0, -1, 1, -1, 6}}